# XCache: cannot init in Laravel 5.1 application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, xcache

I'm developing a Laravel 5.1 web application. 
The application is working absolutely fine on my localhost but when I deploy the website on a cPanel shared hosting it get following error.

> FatalErrorException in Unknown line 0: XCache: Cannot init in Unknown
>   line 0

Sometimes, this error disappears by reloading the page but appears again after reloading several times. I've tried disabling the XCache by editing the `.htaccess` file as described in this [link](http://laravel.io/forum/08-01-2014-laravel-42-is-conflict-with-php5-xcache-module) but it stills generates the same error. How can I resolve this error? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the PHP version to 5.5 and enabling Xcache worked for me.