# Error while hosting CodeIgniter Framework to online server

Tags: codeigniter

I need to solve the below issue:

[image: Error]

When I tried to hosting codeIgniter framework to my online server, this error occurred.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lviscomp/public_html/system/core/Output.php:528)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 573

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: XCache: Cannot init

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

Comment: this error . which file you run occurred error .you use model check model file "echo" print some code remove echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same  [xcache issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305531/xcache-cannot-init-in-laravel-5-1-application) in my Laravel application. I resolved it by upgrading the PHP version.

I think this might help you as well.

1. Go to your cPanel
2. Go to software section and click "select PHP version"
3. Change your PHP version from "native" to 5.4 or 5.5 (It will give you a list of drivers with checkboxes)
4. Select Xcache and enable it
5. Save your settings as well as PHP version

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For Above Error header information already sent...
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)!

**XCache: Cannot init**

Try Disable XCACHE from the Php configuration..
if this doesn't work ..
I think this is a question for your host.